# washed out colors when converting png to jpg in PIL python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

i tried copying the icc profile and applying it to the jpg image but it returns icc profile as none

here is the code

```
from PIL import Image

original = Image.open("image.png")
icc_profile = original.info.get("icc_profile")

new=original.convert('RGB')

new.save("image.jpg", icc_profile=icc_profile)
```

Comment: Given the question, I think (small) example input/output images would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't have to convert anything just open it and save it, PIL will handle the rest

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just have to save it? :)

```
img = Image.open("image.png")
img.save("image.jpg")
```

Voila!

Comment: i just realized its a transparency issue